# C++ Error LNK2001, cannot find error

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ right now and I've been stuck on this for 30 minutes. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Card
{
public:
 Card();
private:
 int rank;
 int suit;
};

int main()
{
 Card card1;
 return 0;
}
```

I'm still new to c++ but I can't see why this is not working, I am getting error LNK2001 and other topics of the same nature haven't helped (because I'm a noob).

If someone could help me I'd appreciate it a lot, thanks

Comment: Where did you define the constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor for the class Card is not specified. Try using:

```
Card() {
}
```

Or (outside the class):

```
Card::Card() {
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89060d65fb12d99a)